# When using rstatix::get_summary_stats how do I export the results to a .csv file?

Tags: r, rstatix

I am trying to calculate group means from a 4-way mixed ANOVA. The code is working great -- and I can output the results into my console -- but how do I save this table to a file (i.e. export as a .csv)? I tried using the `capture.output()` command, but then it cannot find the object score.

```
##Group Means    
data %>%
  group_by(region, task, production, position) %>%
  get_summary_stats(score, type = "mean_sd")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `readr::write_csv()` (or `write.csv()` from base R)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(readr)
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    get_summary_stats(hp, type="mean_sd") %>% 
    write_csv("my_output.csv")
```

You might also be interested in the `emmeans` package, for getting "expected marginal means" from more complex statistical models.